# Why does a list outside a function get modified by something inside another function? (Python 3.4)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a relative python novice. I have a simple function here that takes in a list and removes an element of the list. However, I noticed that the function actually alters the list outside of the function. For example,

```
def test(lista):
    lista.remove(1)
    return(lista)

def main():
    a = [1,2,3]

    print(a)

    x = test(lista=a)

    print(a)
```

It turns out that the first call to `print(a)`, I get `[1, 2, 3]` as expected, but the second call to `print(a)`, I get `[2, 3]` which doesn't quite make sense to me because I'm not sure why the function `test` would remove the element from `a`. I understand that I pass `a` in as a parameter, but I'm not sure why `lista.remove(1)` would remove the element `1` from both `a` and `lista`.

Thanks!

Comment: `lista` is just another name for the argument that is passed.  That is, `lista` is just a synonym for `a`.  They are the same object.

Comment: You passed in a list and then modified it... its pretty straight forward. If you want to keep the original list, make a copy for the function.

Comment: Is it a good idea to have a function that overwrites the list that you passed in instead of returning a new one?

Comment: I recommend reading Ned Batchelder's [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html). It's one of the best explanations of how stuff like this works.

Answer (score 0):

Python objects are passed-by-object-reference to functions (ruby calls this pass-by-reference but it's different than C++ pass-by-reference). This means that the argument you assign to `lista` is the original object `a`, simply with a new named reference object to the same data.

If you instead copied the list it would not affect the original

```
x = test(lista=list(a))
```

Comment: "Python objects are passed by reference to functions" - while the thing that is passed to the function is a reference, "pass-by-reference" refers to a specific, different parameter passing model. In pass-by-reference, `lista` would be an alias for the caller's variable, rather than both variables referring to a shared object, and assignments to `lista` would affect the caller's variable.

Comment: @user2357112 I was being a bit liberal with the terminology as Ruby calls it pass by reference for the same operation. I updated to clarify that it's not quite the same as traditional pass by reference.

Comment: Do you have a source for Ruby calling this pass by reference? When I google `Ruby pass by reference`, I get zero sources calling it pass by reference. The closest is "pass by value where the value is a reference", like the Java guys call it.

Comment: http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/11/does-python-pass-by-value-or-by.html but http://robertheaton.com/2014/07/22/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value/ calls it Pass-reference-by-value and the O'Reilly book, The Ruby Programming Language calls it out as "arguments are passed by value rather than by reference, but that the values passed are object references". All 3 sources call out that pass-by-reference is a confusing term and that it doesn't translate well from C++ to ruby's (and by corollary python's) object abstaction model